# Foreign Supervising Driver in Ireland

Tags: driving, ireland

Does anyone know if a supervising driver / accompanying driver (i.e. someone who holds a full license who accompanies a driving learner on a provisional license/learner permit) can hold a foreign driving license, or does the license need to be from the same country?

I have a license from the UK and my girlfriend has a provisional Irish license.

I found this useful thread but can't see anything about foreign licenses: [Accompanied Driver Rules/Restrictions](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2055176756).

Thanks.

Comment: Not an official answer but the supervising driver thing is not enforced most of the time. Having a UK driver would be seen almost as going above an beyond.

Comment: Not sure about Ireland, but in the UK the learner supervision is 'not enforced' in the sense of not checked up on, but if you are discovered driving without supervision, or worse get into an accident, you are going to be in serious trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, a foreign license is good enough.

The [Irish RSA website](http://www.rsa.ie/en/RSA/Learner-Drivers/Safe-Driving1/Safety-for-Permit-Holders/) says:

> the person who’s with you must hold a full driving licence for the
>   category of vehicle you are driving for a continuous period of 2
>   years.

It also states that a permit holder can't be an accompanying driver.

The [citizenshipinformation.ie site](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/travel_and_recreation/motoring_1/driver_licensing/learner_driving_permits_for_cars_and_work_vehicles.html) says:

> Car drivers with a learner permit must be accompanied at all times by,
>   and be under the supervision of, someone with a current driving
>   licence for a car. Also, the person accompanying you must have had the
>   driving licence for at least 2 years.

Note that although these are official sources, they are not the law. I think the [Road Traffic Act (1961)](http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/1961/act/24/enacted/en/print.html) is the authoritative source, but I didn't find mention of an accompanying driver there.